# Supported Build.CPU_ABI vs Build.CPU_ABI2 vs Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS

Tags: android, android-ndk, cpu-architecture, abi

Referring [to this document](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html) , I understand that if one or more from the Build.CPU_ABI and Build.CPU_ABI2 is equal to the architecture a specific APK is targets to - then running this apk on this specific device should work.

In practice, what happened when I did an experiment confused me:

I took an Azus device running android 4.4 and check the properties it returns:

`Build.CPU_ABI` = X86

`Build.CPU_ABI2` = armeabi-v7a

But in practice, seems like this device is not supporting armeabi-v7a.
I know this because I tried to install on this device a [version of Facebook which targets armeabi-v7a](https://cdn-root.s3.amazonaws.com/apk%2F36769C46D59859CD%2Fcom.facebook.katana_23_4968884a17c87d97b6ca592f00c839f527eee509.apk) , and it fails with a log indicating that ABI not supported.
Also  I verified this using adb dump badging on the apk, and it returns:

```
'native-code': 'armeabi-v7a'
```

My Questions:

- How can it be that device declaring CPU_ABI2 = armeabi-v7a that not really able to run Facebook version targets armeabi-v7a?

  It is super important to me understand what exactly going on,  since I'm developing an app that exactly like google play suppose to deliver and install to the device applications, and I try to find out what device property will give me indication about the APK I suppose to deliver based on it.

Comment: That looks wrong, its `armeabi-v7a`. Chances are there's a library on the device that has both lib/[armeabi-v7a] and lib/[x86] support in there which the framework is picking up on. Give more information on the device, Azus, is it not Asus?

Comment: @t0mm13b the device is Azus Zenfone model ASUS_Z002

Comment: Its an [Intel atom chipset](https://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench3/6632669) , the fact you tried to install a armv7 version of facebook on the device failed obviously, since x86 and armv7 at low level, are chalk and cheese. The environment setting, Kitkat supports both architectures, the primary variable to use is `Build.CPU_ABI`, ignore the other, as it can run on armv7 anyway. It is down to how Asus built the Android version, from a singular codebase multi-targetting differing platforms.

Comment: @t0mm13b: can I understand from what you are telling me that CPU_ABI2 is not always really an indication I can count on, but I can count always on CPU_ABI?

Comment: @t0mm13b: it is super important to me undestand the differences since I'm developing an app that exactly like google play suppose to deliver and install to the device applications, and I try to find out what device property will give me indication about the APK I suppose to deliver based on it

Comment: CPU_ABI is the primary. Facebook is a prime example of universal apk, in the sense, that NDK native C/C++ code are contained within the apk in which the java/jni makes the appropriate call based on the CPU_ABI. Are you using C/C++ NDK as part of your build?

Comment: I do not use any native code within my own app.  why?

Comment: Thats ok, so its all plain Java and Android SDK, then it will run on differing platforms based on ABI used.

Comment: sorry I'm keeping asking the same question, but still I want to make sure:   are you saying that only the primary ABI is what should be considered, and always?  if - so : then why there is no any reference to this in the documentation?

Comment: It is more for NDK C/C++ builds, where bundling a **native** library code is shared with the apk, rather than anything else

Comment: most intel atom processors (if not all) comes with the library (houdini) that can translate in fly arm to x86, thats why you are able to see `armeabi-v7a` as `CPU_ABI2`. I myself have Asus Zenfone 5 with Atom and have the same CPU_ABIs. My phone normally run arm applications without an issue. One addition: when i had had android 4.4, there were scripts to disable/enable houdini on the phone (accessible through adb), i can't find them after update to android 5.0

Comment: I would suggest to simply install a small APK that only armv-7a: maybe, something is wrong with that strange facebook APK? If you don't want to mess with NDK samples yourself, you can try this link for example http://www.apk4fun.com/apk/1542/